# Get rid of default block style for drupal menu block module

Tags: blocks

After lots of trying, i finally managed to find out how to make my [menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489049/bootstrap-navbar-active-class-drupal) active in drupal 7, using the drupal menu block module.

There is one nasty thing which i can't find just a simple solution for, a default block style is still surrounding my menu, and i need to get rid of that.

I tried to override the blocks using:

menu-block-wrapper--[menu name].tpl.php

Problem is, it changes only everything within the block.

I can't add any pictures yet, but i asked the same question on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548405/theming-menu-block-module-drupal-get-rid-of-default-block-style), so there you will find the example of what i mean with a gray area around my menu block.

Anyone any idea's and suggestions on how to solve this? I know there is something i can do with the theme hooks, but i really got no clue on how to use it to get rid of the gray area...

Comment: Hey Hermes, are you familiar with the Firebug extension for Firefox or other ways to inspect which html elements and corresponding css that are responsible for the styles you're trying to change?  I'm thinking the gray box may be due to css that applies to the block the menu is in, or maybe even to the menu that appears in the main nav section of your theme, or other possibilities.  In any case, do you know how to check the html and css of specific elements on your page to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Hey, yeah its the default css from drupal where its wrapped in. <?php print render($classes); ?> that puts in there. I found a way to work around it, by changing the general block template <?php if($block->module == "menu_block"): ?>
 <?php print $content; ?>
<?php else: ?> the usual template <?php endif;?> This works for now, but it doesn't look like pretty way of doing it. If you know a more clean way of doing it, i will glad to hear it :)